# How to create a function which calls edit-indirect-region and then changes the mode in the buffer?

Tags: defun

I'm beginner user of Emacs and I found trouble while trying to bind a custom function to a key.

I successfully bind some keys to `edit-indirect-region` using following code:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-c C-e") 'edit-indirect-region)
```

Now what I am trying to achieve is to bind a custom function which first calls `edit-indirect-region` then switches to the buffer and calls `scss-mode`.

**This is what I tried:**

```
(defun edit-indirect-scss (beg end &optional display-buffer)
  (interactive)
  (edit-indirect-region beg end &optional display-buffer)
  (scss-mode))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-c C-s") 'edit-indirect-scss)
```

**I am receiving this kind of error:**

```
funcall-interactively: 
Wrong number of arguments: (lambda (beg end &optional display-buffer) (interactive) (edit-indirect-region beg end &optional display-buffer) (scss-mode)), 0
```

How can I get it to work?

**EDIT:**

As @Drew suggested I did change my function definition to:

```
(defun edit-indirect-scss (beg end &optional display-buffer)
  (interactive)
  (edit-indirect-region beg end display-buffer))
```

but I'm still experiencing an error while trying to visual select few lines and then hit `"C-c C-c C-s"`

```
funcall-interactively: Wrong number of arguments: (lambda (beg end &optional display-buffer) (interactive) (edit-indirect-region beg end display-buffer)), 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting the answer to fulfil the question.
I got several issues with code which inhibited me from creating a proper function.

The **first** mistake is like @Drew noticed the `&optional` keyword.

The **second** mistake I made is that I should use `(interactive "r")`, it gets the region the user highlights and passes it to `begin`, `end` variables.

Here is how it should look like at this point.

```
(defun edit-indirect-scss (begin end)
  "Enables to quickly edit scss mode in the indirect buffer"
  (interactive "r")
  (edit-indirect-region begin end)
  (scss-mode))
```

The **last** part is that I should switch to a buffer which `(edit-indirect-region begin end)` creates. To achieve it used `switch-to-buffer` function.

Final working example:

```
 (defun edit-indirect-scss (begin end)
  "Enables to quickly edit scss mode in the indirect buffer"
  (interactive "r")
  (switch-to-buffer (edit-indirect-region begin end))
  (scss-mode))
```

The code solves the problem. It firstly gets the region highlighted by the user, then creates new indirect buffer and switch to it and then changes the mode of the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You have this

```
(defun edit-indirect-scss (beg end &optional display-buffer)
  (interactive)
  (edit-indirect-region beg end &optional display-buffer)
  (scss-mode))
```

This sexp passes 4, not 3, arguments to function `edit-indirect-region`:

```
(edit-indirect-region beg end &optional display-buffer)
```

Get rid of the argument `&optional`.

`&optional` is used as a keyword in a defining special form such as `defun`.  You do not pass it as an actual argument to the function.

Comment: Hi @Drew I still have the same error I did edit my question to let you help me.

Comment: `(interactive "r")`

Comment: Thanks @jpkotta now my code looks like this 
`(defun edit-indirect-scss (begin end)
  (interactive "r")
  (edit-indirect-region begin end))`
There are no error but the problem is that the buffer is created but Emacs did not switch to it.

Comment: Ok I managed it to work i will post a full answer today, thanks guys you are all great.

Comment: Glad it was helpful. But please keep in mind that emacs.SE is not a please-debug-my-code site. It is a Q&A site. (And comments can be deleted at any time.) Questions about code should be about something specific - one thing per question.

Comment: I know the rules of the `SE` and I did not want you to debug my code. You gave me a nice hint I really appreciate it. Also I don't want to be rude but IMO my question was very specific. As far as i know you should improve the quality of your answer because it not actually solves the problem. Let me edit it for you.

Comment: Ok i did edit your answer. Thanks one more time and have a nice day.

Comment: Your question was specific - about the error you got. I answered that specifically. Then there was a back & forth between you and jpkotta about other problems with the code - *in comments*. It's that that I was referring to. The specific question about the error message is a good question for emacs.SE. The winding comment thread that eventually results in code that does what you want is not. If it helped, great. You can post your own answer, BTW, which can incorporate info you might have gotten from comments - and you can accept your own answer. (Comments can be deleted anytime.)